# Conversion from MathML equation to flash?

Tags: html, flash, png, mathml

I am a beginner at this and I need some guidance.

The website I am working with primarily works in flash. Using a [HTML equation editor](http://www.mathdox.org/formulaeditor/), I want users to be able to enter equations and then use them in the flash environment for display. The MathML source code of the equation will be saved. I'm just confused as to how to take an equation that is developed from a HTML equation editor and use in a flash environment. The user must also be able to edit the equation (changing around the MathML source code). Is there a method to display MathML in flash or do I have to export the equation as a PNG image to use and edit in the flash environment. Thanks.

Comment: Why not moving away from Flash? Be aware that only Firefox has a good native support to MathML right now. If you expected to have access with Chrome or others web browsers other than Firefox you should take a look at MathJax.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I work on this tool.

Maybe [Alfred's Equation Editor (AlfredEq)](http://sharemath.com/AlfredEq-README.html) could do what you ask.